# Copy directory overwriting existing files

Tags: vb.net, file, directory, rename

I have programed my self stuck and need some help

I have programed a way for templates to be coppied over from one directory to another

```
     'My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("C:\MYapp\TEMPLATES\" & ComboBox1.Text, "C:\Myapp\PROJECTS\" & form1.label1.Text & "\Template")
```

however if the files already exists the orriginals are over written. somehow I need to be able to rename the files with in the `"C:\MYapp\TEMPLATES\" & ComboBox1.Text` during the copying process

is there a way of still doing this?

I'm ussing VB.net

EDDIT:

```
For Each CONTENTS_FILES In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\myapp\TEMPLATES\" & ComboBox1.Text)

    ' do whatever wtih filename
    System.IO.File.Copy("C:\myapp\TEMPLATES\" & ComboBox1.Text & CONTENTS_FILES, C:\myapp\PROJECTS\" & PROJECTS.PROJECTlabel.Text & "\Template\" & TimeOfDay & CONTENTS_FILES)
next
```

however I am now lost in my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid overwriting existing files, you will need to copy the files one at a time and test to see if each one already exists:

```
If System.Io.File(THISFILENAME).Exists Then
    ' use a different name
Else
     ' continue
End If
```

Comment: Yes.  The code I showed would go inside a loop such as the one you added in your Edit.  You need to fix the type of some of your vars such as `CONTENTS_FILES` what is it?  And rather than use TIMEOFDAY, do something simple like `& ".bak"`.